# How to override JavaScript array sort method?

Tags: javascript, sorting, overriding, overloading

**THIS QUESTION STILL HAS NOT BEEN CORRECTED ANSWERED AS OF Monday Oct 31** *(People are wrongly answer it as if I'm asking for array.sort to be modified but I'm not asking that)*

How do I override the built in JavaScript sort method for a *single* array (not `Array.sort`) with the radix-msd algorthim?

I have the algorithm for the radix msd sort, it's

```
// radix most-significant-bit sort for integers
//arr: array to be sorted
//begin: 0
//end: length of array
//bit: maximum number of bits required to represent numbers in arr
function radixsort (arr, begin, end, bit) {
    var i, j, mask;
    i = begin;
    j = end;
    mask = 1 << bit;
    while(i < j) {
        while(i < j && !(arr[i] & mask)) {
            ++i;
        }
        while(i < j && (arr[j - 1] & mask)) {
            --j;
        }
        if(i < j) {
            j--;
            var tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
            i++;
        }
    }
    if(bit && i > begin) {
        radixsort(arr, begin, i, bit - 1);   //    <=== RECURSIVE FUNCTION
    }
    if(bit && i < end) {
        radixsort(arr, i, end, bit - 1);     //    <=== RECURSIVE FUNCTION
    }
}
```

And my JavaScript object array is:

```
homes[0].price;
homes[0].address;
homes[0].city;
homes[0].state;
homes[0].zip;
```

So that, when I call "`homes.sort()`" - I want it to sort the entire `homes[x]` array based on the `price` using my `radix sort` array from above. *How do I do that?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think modifying `Array.prototype.sort` is **very** dangerous (because all other codes probably using sort() will be affected). Here's the code though:

```
//Just use this function like radixsort(homes,0,homes.length,32)
function radixsort (arr, begin, end, bit) {
    var i, j, mask;
    i = begin;
    j = end;
    mask = 1 << bit;
    while(i < j) {
        while(i < j && !(arr[i].price & mask)) {
            ++i;
        }
        while(i < j && (arr[j - 1].price & mask)) {
            --j;
        }
        if(i < j) {
            j--;
            var tmp = arr[i].price;
            arr[i].price = arr[j].price;
            arr[j].price = tmp;
            i++;
        }
    }
    if(bit && i > begin) {
        radixsort(arr, begin, i, bit - 1);
    }
    if(bit && i < end) {
        radixsort(arr, i, end, bit - 1);
    }
}
//If you really want to modify default sort function:
Array.prototype.sort = function(){
    radixsort(this,0,this.length,32); //Use 'this' to access (get reference) to the array.
}
```

Comment: But if I did the top example, how would radixsort know to sort on the Price attribute of my array? I see you made the function assume the Price attribute existed in the array but I'd like to generalize the radixsort function to not assume the Price attribute.

Comment: Actually the OP never claimed to want to override `Array.prototype.sort` (that would obviously be dangerous and foolish as you say!) -- they just wanted to use the `homes.sort()` syntax.  By using the term "override" I think the OP made clear the desire to use a sort method just for the homes array and not to change the behavior for *all* arrays.

Comment: **@JiminP (or ANYONE), if you can help me generalize this so that I don't have to hardcode "Price" into the radix sort function, I'll make this answer correct/accepted. See my comment above.**

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to override the [`sort` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), you simply need to pass your comparer function to the `sort` method as a parameter.

The function signature for the parameter is `function (a, b)` where `a` is the item being compared to `b`.

If you need a different implementation of sort, set it as a different function rather than overriding the default behavior. You can do this for all arrays using:

```
Array.prototype.radixsort = function ( ...params... )
```

Which will allow you to call

```
[1,2,3].radixsort(...params...);
```

Alternatively, you can add a utility function to `Array`:

```
Array.radixsort = function ( ...params... )
```

Which will be called as:

```
Array.radixsort([1,2,3], ...params...);
```

Comment: I'm not looking to overload/override Array.sort, just Homes.sort

Comment: N/A - This answer doesn't apply since I'm not looking to override Array.sort. Only homes.sort (unless advised else wise).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Ray Toal's and zzzzBov's discussion:

```
  function defaultCompare(a, b) {
      var a_str = str(a);
      var b_str = str(b);
      if (a_str < b_str) {
          return -1;
      } else if (a_str > b_str) {
          return 1;
      } else {
          return 0;
      }
   }

   homes.sort = function (compare_func) {
       compare_func = compare_func || defaultCompare;
       RadixSort(this, 0, this.length, 64);
   }
```

There are probably typos in the above, but it should be a step toward a more complete implementation.

Answer (score -2):

Your question is asking two things:

1. How does one call `sort` on an array but call a function other than `Array.sort`?
2. How do you make the sort algorithm use a particular field without hardcoding it?

The answer to the first question is to attach a `sort` method on the `homes` object itself:

```
homes.sort = function () {radixSort(homes, 0, homes.length, bit);}
```

As one of the commenters, and other answerers have pointed out, doing this can be very confusing. For one thing, `Arrays.sort` takes a second parameter which is a comparison function. Radix sort is a distribution-based sort, not a comparison-based sort, so "overriding" `sort` in this way doesn't make much sense. You would be ignoring a comparison function were someone to pass it in.

But there's another problem. Your `radixSort` as written does not work because it does not compare prices. One of the answers hardcodes the price, but you said you did not like this situation. You can fix this as follows: add a fifth parameter which is a field name. If undefined, use the array element itself, otherwise select the field. Something like this (not tested):

```
function radixsort (arr, begin, end, bit, field) {
    var i = begin, j = end , mask = 1 << bit;
    // Use the value of the field at i if present, otherwise the whole element
    var at = function (i) {return field in arr ? arr[i][field] : arr[i]};
    while (i < j) {
        while (i < j && !(arr.at(i) & mask)) {
            ++i;
        }
        while (i < j && (arr.at(j-1) & mask)) {
            --j;
        }
        if (i < j) {
            j--;
            var tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (bit && i > begin) {
        radixsort(arr, begin, i, bit - 1);
    }
    if (bit && i < end) {
        radixsort(arr, i, end, bit - 1);
    }
}
```

Now you can say:

```
homes.sort = function () {radixSort(homes, 0, homes.length, 64, 'price');}
```

However, keep in mind the following caveat:

**CAVEAT**: If `price` is a floating-point value, a radix sort probably won't work. Your best bet is to just use `Array.prototype.sort` and pass in a comparator to sort on different fields.

Comment: don't override default functions with new behavior, it will cause massive headaches for future debugging.

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm inclined to agree with you for `sort`, but I wouldn't take that as general advice because the default function `toString` is ridiculous and meant to be overridden. :)  I know what you mean though.  Still, the question has merit from a technical standpoint, so I edited the answer to address your concern.

Comment: `toString` and `valueOf` are special cases that are used as a common interface to all objects, and are expected to have values overridden. You have to maintain that common interface for them to work correctly. You wouldn't return an object or number from `toString`, so *if* you're going to override `sort`, you'd have to make it work with the existing interface, which involves the first parameter being a comparer function.

Comment: Ha! and that's why it's hard if not impossible in this case. Radix sort is a distribution sort, not a comparison sort, so very true, treating `sort` as a generic method a la `toString` and `toValue` doesn't make any sense, since a radix sort doesn't take a comparator at all. Still the question was interesting in its own right, as the OP was trying to make an object-specific method, but yes, in this particular case, it's not at all the right thing to do.